# Como pegar o avô de um termo na taxonomy no Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Como pegar o avô de um termo na taxonomy no Wordpress? Considere a seguinte árvore:

```
-Cidade
  -Farmacias
     -farmacia central
     -farmacia São José
```

Quero pegar o nome da cidade da farmacia central, por exemplo.

Comment: Você quer pegar posts dessa categoria, é isso?

Comment: Preciso pegar o nome da cidade que a farmacia "tal" pertence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode fazer uma coisa aparecida, que peguei de uma [resposta](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/24794/get-the-the-top-level-parent-of-a-custom-taxonomy-term) do StackExchange do próprio Wordpress:

```
// determine the topmost parent of a term
function get_term_top_most_parent($term_id, $taxonomy){
    // começa do atual
    $parent  = get_term_by( 'id', $term_id, $taxonomy);
    // subir a árvore até encontrar um termo com parent = '0'
    while ($parent->parent != '0'){
        $term_id = $parent->parent;

        $parent  = get_term_by( 'id', $term_id, $taxonomy);
    }
    return $parent;
}
```